# Android VideoView detect video is soon finish

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to know whether the movie is just one minute away from the the end.
So, I use the below code to detect. However, the player is hang and it can't do anything.
Could somebody correct my code? Thanks!

```
public Runnable mPlayToEnd = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while(true)
        {
            if(mVideoDisplayView.getDuration() - mVideoDisplayView.getCurrentPosition() <= 1000 * 60)
            {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(WILL_END);  
                   sendBroadcast(intent);
                   mSendEndEvent = false;
                   Log.d("123","--Duration = " + mVideoDisplayView.getDuration() + "--");
                   Log.d("123","--Current = " + mVideoDisplayView.getCurrentPosition() + "--");
                   Log.d("123","--Soon End--");
            }
        }
    }
};
     Handler mCheckEndHandler = new Handler();
     mCheckEndHandler.post(mPlayToEnd);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hangs because you have an infinite while(true) loop, which you never break, and it tries to run full speed to check whether you're 1 minute from the end. What you could do is to check periodically, eg. every 1 second, and then process accordingly, so your code might looks something as:

```
public Runnable mPlayToEnd = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mmVideoDisplayView.getDuration() - mVideoDisplayView.getCurrentPosition() <= 1000 * 60) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(WILL_END);  
            sendBroadcast(intent);
            mSendEndEvent = false;
            Log.d("123","--Duration = " + mVideoDisplayView.getDuration() + "--");
            Log.d("123","--Current = " + mVideoDisplayView.getCurrentPosition() + "--");
            Log.d("123","--Soon End--");
        }
        else {
            mCheckEndHandler.postDelayed(mPlayToEnd, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Then declare your handler as class member variable, so that it's accessible in your runnable, and start it:

```
mCheckEndHandler = new Handler();
mCheckEndHandler.post(mPlayToEnd);
```

What will happen is your runnable will check the condition, and if it's satisfied, it will send the broadcast, otherwise, it will run itself again in 1 second (1000ms). The whole process repeats until your condition is true.